# c# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#

First of all I think my issue is pretty different than the other topics in stackoverflow since I've tried the solutions in them.

I'm using .NET 4.5 :

```
        HttpWebRequest MainRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);


        WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = MainRequest.Headers;
        MainRequest.Method = "GET";

        MainRequest.Host = "aro.example.com";
        MainRequest.Timeout = 20000;
        MainRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        MainRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36";
        myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
        myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        MainRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        MainRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        MainRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebResponse MainResponse = (HttpWebResponse)MainRequest.GetResponse();
```

This throws the exception the underlying ...

I added : 
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

I get no exception now, but also no response until the timeout occurs.

Comment: `i don't receive any response till the timeout hits` have you tried pinging the host to see if you can reach it at all?

Comment: Yes i do receive response by pinging the host

Comment: What is meant by _"This throws the exception the underlying ..."_?  Have you tried running Wireshark or other packet capture to see what's happening on the wire?

Comment: is it a 'https' url ? open the url in the browser, open your browser's wed-dev tool, copy all request headers and make sure you send them in that format in your code.

Comment: @Vignesh.N its what i did and yes its an https url